# Chromecast SDK MediaRouteActionProvider Bug

Tags: android, google-cast

I tried searching for this and didn't find anything, posting this here if it helps anyone. I was running into an issue where a test device of mine running Android 4.0.3 would not display the Chromecast menu item when a device was discovered (where the chromecast menu item specifies a MediaRouteActionProvider). There appears to be a bug in the SDK for devices running below 4.1.2 as I did not have this issue with an S4 or HTC One (both running 4.3). The temporary workaround that I found for this is to simply add another menu item so that the Chromecast menu item was not the only item in the menu. This appears to be consistent with the sample projects in GitHub as they for some reason had a dummy "settings" menu item. Removing that settings menu item and running the sample project on my 4.0.3 yielded my original problem. Long story short: if you're testing the SDK on devices running below 4.1.2 and are having issues seeing the chromecast menu item, try adding a dummy menu item. Hope that helps someone.